# Decode particular value for key of Data using JSONDecoder in Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this kind of data. But I haven’t serialised it yet into JSON

```
{ 
  "status":"ok",
  "totalResults":5899,
  "articles":[{//some key value pairs},
              {//some key value pairs}
   ]
}
```

I want to parse array of articles using decodable protocol.

I know how to do this if I have only articles array but in above case how can I first find the data of articles and parse it to my model using JSONDecodable.

Comment: Paste your JSON data on https://www.json4swift.com/ and you will get the data with codable protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly declare struct of those types.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let status : String
    let totalResults : Int
    let articles : [Article]
}

struct Article : Decodable {
    {//some key value pairs},
    {//some key value pairs}
}
```

Suppose the *json* string is *jsonStr*.
Now convert this json into `data`.

```
let data = Data(jsonStr.utf8)
```

Now try to decode this data.

```
let decodedStruct = fromJSON(data)
```

Here is the definition of `fromJSON()` method

```
static func fromJSON(jsonData: Data) -> Root? {
     let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
     do {
          let root = try jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
          return root
     } catch {
          return nil
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary becomes a struct and an array of dictionaries becomes an array of the struct

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let status : String
    let totalResults : Int
    let articles : [Article]
}

struct Article : Decodable {
    let aKey : AType
    let anotherKey : AnotherType
}
```

Comment: Means to get values of articles I need to make two structs and its compulsory to make. 
Where if i serialize it with JSONSeriliazer I can fetch values of articles without taking "status" and "totalArticles" into consideration. Please correct me if if i'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: Yes you have to define proper structure, you can't decode just the articles.